# How To Count The Number Of Printed Pages In Print Preview Excel with C#?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I want to know the total number of the printed pages in advanced.
To count the number of printed pages before printing, I will go to the Print to view the counting number.
click File -> Print, then I can view the number of printed pages.
[image]

I can count the number of printed pages in a sheet (in the picture above is 2). But when I change print setting to "entire workbook", the number of page in Print preview will change. I don't know the way to get the number of printed pages.
[image]

```
Excel.Worksheet esh1 = oWB.Worksheets["List of holidays"];
MessageBox.Show(esh1.PageSetup.Pages.Count.ToString());
```

Can you help me to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Iterate all the worksheets, get the number for each one, and add them up?

Comment: Actually, I want to know if whether the user is choose Print "Entire workbook". So I think I will count the number of Pages in print preview. If the number of page in print preview = 4 -> user choose entire workbook. If number of page in print preview =<4-> user don't choose entire workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, as Ahmed Abdelhameed commented, with one difference - count pages only for visible sheets:

```cs
            Excel.Workbook xlWB = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook; // or other way you get an instance of the workbook 
            long pagesCount = 0;

            foreach (Excel.Worksheet xlSht in xlWB.Sheets)
            {
                if (xlSht.Visible == Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible)
                {
                    pagesCount += xlSht.PageSetup.Pages.Count;
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show(pagesCount.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I want to know if whether the user is choose Print "Entire workbook". So I think I will count the number of Pages in print preview. If the number of page in print preview = 4 -> user choose entire workbook. If number of page in print preview =<4-> user don't choose entire workbook.